# Custom AlertDialog deformed whenever soft keyboard is shown

Tags: android, layout, android-softkeyboard

My app is showing a custom AlertDialog with 4 spots for the login screen.

Its working ok on the Galaxy S3 (Android 4.1.2) but on the Galaxy Xcover (Android 2.3.6 and 3,65 inches screen) the dialogs gets deformed whenever the soft keyboard is shown:

[image]

When I hide the soft keyboard again the dialog is correctly shown

Not sure if it depends on the Android version or the screen size.

Any idea about how to solve this problem? Is there anything special that you have to do with the custom AlertDialog?

```
<LinearLayout 
              android:id="@+id/llPin"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"

              android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPin1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:password="true"
                    android:maxLength="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editTextPin2"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/editTextPin2"
                    android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/editTextPin2"
                    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/editTextPin2"
                    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/editTextPin2"
                    android:minWidth="30dp"/>

            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPin2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:password="true"
                    android:maxLength="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editTextPin3"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/editTextPin3"
                    android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/editTextPin3"
                    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/editTextPin3"
                    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/editTextPin3"
                    android:minWidth="30dp"/>

            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPin3"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:password="true"
                    android:maxLength="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editTextPin4"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/editTextPin4"
                    android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/editTextPin4"
                    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/editTextPin4"
                    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/editTextPin4"
                    android:minWidth="30dp"/>

            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPin4"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:password="true"
                    android:maxLength="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editTextPin1"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/editTextPin1"
                    android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/editTextPin1"
                    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/editTextPin1"
                    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/editTextPin1"
                    android:minWidth="30dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```